# Minimalistic destructors?

Tags: c++, oop

We have some issue with my friend. Assume, we have a class which implements database connection, like this:

```
class DB
{
void Connect();
void Disconnect();
// ...
~DB();
};
```

In my opinion, destructor should be minimalistic, which means destructor should not call Disconnect method when connection was established. I think, that this should be done by separate method (disconnect() in this example). Am I correct, or my friend is?

PS. Community Wiki?

Comment: How about a bool m_isConnected; and in deconstructor, if connected you disconnect, that way stale connections are left over.

Comment: More for curiosity - how minimalist should destructors be in your world? What control over an object's resources should it not have? The [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) uses destructors to clean up resources acquired by the object. Breaking out resource cleanup into disparate functions can lead to exception unsafe code.

Comment: Community Wiki doesn't exist anymore. And even if it was not the case, why would you set this question community wiki ?

Comment: "What language? It matters."   How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAII idioms says: acquire in the constructor and release in the deconstructor. You must guarantee that your deconstructor will NOT throw anything. Otherwise you will have core dump (or undefined behaviour) if your object deconstructor will throw an exception during the stack-unwind.

Also in your specific case I will probably implement a reference counting mechanism, and call the disconnect just when you haven't any more object using the connection.

Answer (score 8):

Your destructor should be enough to clean up all the resources that were acquired during the object lifetime. This might or might not include ending connnections. Otherwise who will do the cleanup if an exception is thrown?

Comment: Agreed... just make sure you don't call any virtual methods during destruction.

Answer (score 2):

According to the syntax it looks like C++. Am I correct? Because if so, you can (and it is highly recommended to) use the RAII idiom. That means that you aquire the DB connection on construction, free it (disconnect) on destruction.

Good reference: [What's RAII All About?](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=502)

Comment: Language not specified, I am fan of Java (isn't it obvious? ;] ) and my friend is C++ geek.

Comment: @TBH: In garbage-collected languages, AFAIK, there is no guarantee that destructors are ever invoked. In C++ there is. Make your own conclusions.

Comment: @visitor: I don't know Java, but C# has the `IDisposable` interface and Python the `__del__(self)` method which ARE guaranteed to be called, though they might not be called immediately (not until the GC realizes the object can be collected). Are you talking about no call at all, or the possibility of waiting a long time before it is called ?

Comment: Java has ".finalize()" method, which do exactly the same what you have told. I was talking about situation, where destructor will never alter the state of connection.

Comment: @Matthieu: My Python reference says: "It is **not** guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits."

Comment: @UncleBens: right, though I guess this is more a caveat regarding interrupts (segfaults ?), I have never hit the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the class user point of view, I believe it is better to try and `disconnect` the database connection when it should instead of assuming the destructor will do the job.

However, bad things happen, most notably exceptions, and you must guarantee that cleanup will occur regardless of what happened. This is why your destructor should nevertheless `disconnect` if necessary (i.e: if it hasn't been explicitly called by the user).

Comment: I know, but... I think when someone uses a class he must know how to operate that class. Isn't it obvious to call .disconnect() before destroying that object? I believe so.

Comment: @TBH I agree, but you can't always expect the execution to reach your call to `disconnect`